# System Configuration for 3 node elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking to setup a 3 node elasticsearch cluster on ubuntu VMs. 1 VM per node. There is currently a single index that is roughly 1.2 GB w/ about 8 million documents at this point. This will definitely grow substantially over the course of the application. This application will be used by several hundreds of users. I'm looking for suggestions on # of processors per machines, memory, disk space, and elastic search configurations. Any help with this would be appreciated or if you could point me to resources which might help in this regard.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going to through section:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/deploy.html
and 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-performance.html

Ideally the first URL itself will give you the answes you are looking out for.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I missed that when I was looking. I appreciate it!